# Как изменить url через htaccess — GET запрос + PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

У меня есть страница:

```
site.ru/profile?id=100
```

Хочу, чтобы было:

```
site.ru/p/100
```

Как это сделать?

P.S. У меня есть уже код .htaccess который убирает .php в конце (написал для тех, кто может подумать что я неправильно написал сам GET)

Comment: То есть вам необходим Redirect через .htaccess?

Comment: Да! через .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так (не тестировал, но в теории должно работать):

```
#Если URL содержит profile
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}% ^profile(.*) [NC]
#Если URL содержит id
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}% id=(\d+) [NC]
#Делаем 301 Redirect
RewriteRule .*p/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]